# How to hide the "sharing connexion" bar in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know how to hide the "sharing connexion" bar because it actually shifts the labels, buttons, etc. in Swift.

Here's what I would like to hide:

https://www.libellules.ch/images/partage_connexion_iphone3.png

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You can't hide it. The solution is to use proper constraints

Comment: @LeoDabus then how can I detect when it is shown?